# Why is this an index error?

Tags: python, list, tuples, string-formatting

This is my first post, so I apologize if this has been answered previously. I have tried to look through the Python 3 documentation on string formatting and lists, and reviewed similar formatting questions here on SO.

I want to take the string (data1), break it into a list (bigData), and print out a statement using the list items. *Eventually, the idea would be to read in a csv file, break it up, and print out a response, but I've tried to simplify the process since there's an error.*

> "Hello, John Doe. Your current balance is $53.44."

However, I'm not sure why the following code is throwing an IndexError, much less a tuple index.

```
data1 = "John,Doe,53.44"
bigData = data1.split(",")
bigData[-1] = float(bigData[-1])

print(bigData) # test - []'s indicate a list, not tuple?

greeting = "Hello, {} {}. Your current balance is ${}."

print(greeting.format(bigData))
```

My guess is that bigData is heterogeneous, which implies a tuple. If I substitute a string value instead of 53.44 (so data1 and bigData are homogeneous), it throws the same error.

```
data1 = "John,Doe,random"
bigData = data1.split(",")

print(bigData) # test - []'s indicate a list, not tuple?

greeting = "Hello, {} {}. Your current balance is {}."

print(greeting.format(bigData))
```

However, if I convert the original to Python 2.x string formatting, it formats correctly without an error.

```
data1 = "John,Doe,53.44"
bigData = data1.split(",")
bigData[-1] = float(bigData[-1])

print(bigData) # test - []'s indicate a list, not tuple?

greeting = "Hello, %s %s. Your current balance is $%.2f."

print(greeting % tuple(bigData))
```

1. Why is it converting my string to a tuple?
2. How do I write this work in Python 3?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably you need to unpack the list/tuple, cause format() expects that you'll do that:
`greeting.format(*bigData)` should help.
*Edit:* Format will try to convert each arg to a string first, so it converts your entire list to a string and then complains about insufficient number of args. You can see that by executing '{}'.format(bigData) for example.

Comment: Why don't you do `"Hello, {} {}. Your current balance is {}.".format(X, Y)`? Also, what is your exact error message?

Comment: I'm pretty new, so I didn't even know unpacking was a thing. I gave Alexander the answer because that's what got the code working. Yann did a great job of explaining why that works and where I was confused.

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the splat (`*`) to unpack your arguments (your `format` string wants three arguments but you only give it one, a list containter).

```
print(greeting.format(*bigData))
```

Also, you may want:

```
bigData[-1] = str(round(float(bigData[-1]), 2))
```

Comment: Reference to [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) from the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: A lot of the comments below help to expand on why this works the way it does, but this is what I needed.

And thanks for the suggestions on rounding bigData!

Answer (score 0):

The [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method takes positional arguments, not a single list. You need to unpack your list `bigData` using the `*` operator:

```
data1 = "John,Doe,random"
bigData = data1.split(",")

print(bigData)  # test - []'s indicate a list, not tuple?

greeting = "Hello, {} {}. Your current balance is {}."

print(greeting.format(*bigData))  # here's the change
```

You're correct that `bigData` is a list, not a tuple, `str.split` returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

I can see how this is surprising, though what surprises me is that the traceback doesn't show that the exception occurs in the `format` call.

Python's lists can be heterogenous just like tuples; this is because the common type they store is object references, which all things in Python are. The tuple is actually the argument list to the `format` method, in this case `(bigData,)`. It ran out of arguments when looking for things to format, since you had three `{}` placeholders but only one argument (the list `bigData`). You can use `greeting.format(*bigData)` to unpack the list and use its contents as arguments.

The `%` formatting doesn't encounter this error because it actually expects a tuple (or one item) in the right operand.

A more idiomatic and legible approach might actually be to go to the `csv` module already:

```
import csv, io
data1 = "John,Doe,random"
for row in csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(data1),
        "givenname surname balance".split()):
    greeting = "Hello, {givenname} {surname}. Your current balance is {balance}."
    print(greeting.format(**row))
```

This lets us assign meaningful names to the columns, including reordering them in the format string if needed. I've left out the float conversion, and by the way, `decimal.Decimal` may be better for that use.

Comment: Minor quibbles:  "The % formatting doesn't encounter this error because it actually expects a sequence in the right operand."  Not a sequence.  A tuple.  `"%s %s" % [1, 2]` raises a `TypeError`.  Also when there is only one item to be formatted it will accept either a one item tuple or the item by itself.

Comment: Thank you for the detail. I figured it had something to do with format, but I didn't understand what was going on.

Also, I agree with your adding names to the formatting. That's one reason I wanted to figure this out in python 3 syntax - it reads a lot more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The `str.split()` method returns a list, by definition.

I think you've misunderstood something you've read - heterogeneous vs. homogeneous refer to *typical use cases* of tuples vs. lists.  Having the types of all the elements match or not does not magically cause the container to change to the other type!

Comment: Being new to python, I'm sure I've misunderstood something. However, my thought was that since python dynamically types, I wondered if it assumed it was a tuple since it was heterogeneous.

Comment: There is never any assumption of type.  Whatever created it, explicitly created either a list or a tuple (or some other type).